# How do I put these two python scripts together?

Tags: python

I am trying to write a script when motion is detected it will send me an email,
can anyone help me put this script here

```
    enter import smtplib

smtpUser = 'mygmail@gmail.com'
smtpPass = 'mypassword'

toAdd = 'reciever@gmail.com'
fromAdd = smtpUser

subject = 'Test'
header = 'To: ' + toAdd + '\n' + 'From: ' + fromAdd + '\n' + 'Subject: ' + subject
body = 'From pi'

print header + '\n' + body

s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)

s.ehlo()
s.starttls()
s.ehlo()

s.login(smtpUser, smtpPass)
s.sendmail(fromAdd, toAdd, header + '\n' + body)

s.quit()
```

Into this script here if any motion is detected

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(10,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(21,GPIO.IN)

while True:
    input_state = GPIO.input(21)
    if input_state == True:
        GPIO.output(10,1)
        print "motion detected"
        time.sleep(2)
        GPIO.output(10,0)
        time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: This being a programming question, it would be best asked on the [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) board.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best you ask this question on Stack Overflow, this is out of scope for this site.

Anyways, from your code it looks like that the `if input_state == True:` is the condition that detects motion, so you need to put your entire e-mail sending script inside that if code block.